# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header problems with login

Tags: node.js, passport.js

It's my third day struggling with this issue.

I am getting this error:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 502. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled

However, I have no such problem when performing get request from the same server. I intentionally was breaking cors / headers setting to now allow the front end to access the api and found out the problem is with login. I tried performing post request for login with my own api and with axios, however I failed both times. At this point I dont know where to look for the issue. My app.js api file looks like this:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:3000', 'front end'];
    var origin = req.headers.origin;

    if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1) {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
    }
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
});
```

On front logging in looks like this:

```
export const handleLogin = (email, password) => {
    return function (dispatch) {
        let params = { email, password };
        Api.post('/auth', params).then((res) => {
            //dispatch(fetchUser2());
            if(res.user){
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_USER,
                    payload: res.user
                })
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But maybe issue somehow lies in passport, so Im also pasting the passport file:

```
module.exports = (passport) => {

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    Employee.findById(id).then((user) => {
      done(null, user);
    });
  });

  //passport strategies
  passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true,
  },
    function (req, email, password, done) {
      Employee.findOne({ email: email }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }

        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
        }

        if (password != user.password) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
        }
        return done(null, user);
      }).catch(errors => {
        return done(errors, null);
      })
    }
  ));
}
```

and finally a route for auth in api:

```
 app.post('/auth', function (req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            if (!user) {
                return res.status(401).send({
                    success: false,
                    msg: 'User not found'
                });
            }
            req.logIn(user, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }
                res.status(200).send({
                    user: user,
                    msg: 'You're logged in'
                });
                return;
            });
        })(req, res, next);
    });
```

After trying dummy post and get requests im almost certainly sure its passport's fault, because other post requests work

Comment: *The response had HTTP status code 502* — That’s the problem you need to fix and it has nothing to do with your CORS configuration. It likely indicates a server somewhere is just unreachable — because of a firewall or some port not being open or the server not actually even being up and running, or something.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `set` it should be `setHeader` instead `header`

```
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
```

**EDIT 1**

for production can you allow it to all by setting as:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Comment: Already tried that, makes no difference whatsoever. And again, the header origin works just fine when performing GET request to check for currently logged in user

Comment: Did you try hitting API from `postman`? 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: Oh no, sorry, doesnt work for post request, locally it worked, doesnt with production api

Comment: Okay, can you post request header here?

Comment: @MazMat Updated the answer for allowing to all, can you check that?

Comment: I finally found the issue. The problem lied in the database, there was no connection on the production server. Thats my punishment for not catching errors, rookie mistake. Thank you for your time, at least you werent wrong. However, the wildcard * is not allowed on production servers :)

Comment: glad it helped you anyhow :)